# What is the origin of idiom wrap someone in cotton wool?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin, origin-unknown

I am curious to know the exact origin of the idiom "wrap someone in cotton wool."  I couldn't find much, except

- *Origin: The expression originated in the mid-1800s.*

[[The Idioms]](https://www.theidioms.com/wrap-in-cotton-wool/)

and

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrap%20in%20cotton%20wool&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrap%20in%20cotton%20wool%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwrap%20in%20cotton%20wool%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Well, the early references supplied by Ngram seem mostly to be literal, referring to medical treatments, except for a reference in a story to a son  visiting his mother on her birthday _to take her a little present , which she would wrap in cotton - wool and hide away_. It doesn't take much of a leap of the imagination to get from that kind of description to the metaphorical usage.

Comment: @Kate Ironically, transparent.

Comment: What is the metaphor supposed to mean? The phrase is new to me so it's not clear what is intended.

Comment: @Mitch Coccoon them. [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cocoon). Mollycoddle. Be overly protective.

Comment: A more modern version of this might be "to bubble-wrap someone."

Comment: @KateBunting It used to be common to wrap small, fragile, valuable items in cotton wool before placing them in boxes for storage and transportation. This would be done most typically with glass and ceramic items like glass vials and china figurines. I believe that 'wrapping someone in cotton wool' was a metaphor comparing the over-protective actions and attitudes of the care-giver to the actions of a person protecting a valuable, fragile item. There are also overtones of the care-giver regarding the care receiver as hugely valuable and of hiding them away from the threatening world.

Comment: @BoldBen Do you think I don't know all that? That was the whole point of my comment. Presumably the birthday presents in the story were something like china ornaments which the mother put away instead of having them on display.

Answer (score 4):

This extract from the 1848 publication ['Letters of Mrs Adams'](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Letters_of_Mrs_Adams/58c3AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22him+up+in+cotton+wool%22&pg=PA208&printsec=frontcover) [Abigail Adams; via Google Books]

> *... I expected to have seen a rough, stout, warlike , Roman,– instead*
> *of what I should sooner think of wrapping him up in cotton wool, and*
> *putting him into my pocket, than sending him to contend with*
> *cannon-balls.*

seems an early example showing the development of the metaphorical usage.

Though the metaphor is transparent, it's instructive to see how the final form of  a metaphor might arise, stepwise.

Answer (score 3):

A [Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.it/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA432&dq=%22fuck%20like%20a%20rattlesnake%22&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cotton%20wool&f=false)
by Eric Partridge defines the expression

> Wrap (keep) in cotton wool: cosset, cuddle. Colloquial, from ca. 1870, by mid. 20 c. almost Standard English.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the answer but I believe it is useful.

I found an 1832 publication "Ackermann's Juvenile Forget Me Not" which uses the same idiom, although it is more of a *wrap **something** up in cotton wool* than *wrap **someone** up in cotton wool*. The relevant portion is quoted below [Ackermann's Juvenile Forget Me Not](https://books.google.ro/books?id=G3oOAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ro#v=onepage&q=wrapped%20up%20in%20cotton%20wool&f=false) [R. Ackermann; via Google Books]:

> "O! don't touch, don't touch one thing, Sophia dear! This is the beautiful little vinaigrette which you gave me, and which you see I always keep **wrapped up in cotton wool**.

This seems an earlier example than the example in Edwin's answer.

Comment: Interesting, but it looks like a literal usage rather than a figurative one.